How to prevent new windows from opening in QTTabBar?
I am a user of QTTabBar which allows Windows users to have tabbed browsing in Windows Explorer. When using various programs that have an 'Open in Windows Explorer' buttons, a new Windows Explorer window will pop up, which is something I want to prevent.
In QTTabBar, we generally have two options when opening a directory via right-click:

Open in new Tab
Open in new Window

I am trying to ascertain whether the behavior of opening a new window from external applications is issued via Windows or QTTabBar, and whether QTTabBar is capable of overriding this behavior by opening the link in a new Tab instead of a new Window. The whole reason for this is that opening Windows Explorer links in new windows defeats the purpose of tabbed browsing.
I tried to go ask for help at the QTTabBar forums, but the site seems depracated and no one can post there.
EDIT - I also tried one of the suggestions in an answer below, but that did not work, despite logging off, and back in again:

Window -> Capturing and Exclusion list - enable window capture, also by ShellExecuteHooks :


Running QTTabBar version 1038 on Windows 10 Pro

Have you considered instead of using a third-party application to have tabbed file Explorer just upgrade to Windows 11?

@Ramhound QTTabBar is a third party application, and I am riding out Win10 until it is no longer supported.

I am aware it’s third-party but Windows 11 supports it natively

@Ramhound Well I will eventually be forced to use Win11. Hopefully things are smoother for that, but from what I am readying Win11 is a nightmare for Explorer. Not lookkng forward to that.

Yes, there are settings for opening folders in a new tab:

Window -> Capturing and Exclusion list - enable window capture, also by ShellExecuteHooks
I also recommend leaving Tab -> Activate new tab on as it seems to be a bit more buggy without it

See documentation and important note there:

"Capture" means preventing a folder window from opening, instead open a tab that represents the folder. Currently, QTTabBar can capture folder windows in the following cases:

When a folder is opened from start menu, jumplist of task buttons, and the desktop.
When a folder path is launched by other applications using ShellExecute/ShellExecuteEx API.
Win + >kbd>E key is pressed. (Windows7/8)

Notice that a folder window opened by creating new explorer.exe process won't be captured.

That means the support is limited. Situations when I noticed that new windows are opened:

opening non-standard locations such as control panel or recycle bin
launching folders from some various apps that apparently use different APIs or spawn new explorer.exe process


I was vert excited that there might be a solution for me, but this did not work (I logged off and  back in again before testing). Are you sure this is meant to capture events that are launched from 3rd party applications? I opened up my MO2 mod manager, clicked on one of the files' options to 'Open in Explorer' but doing do simply opened another instance of Windows Explorer instead of opening the link in a new tab of the already opened instance of Windows Explorer. - Also, I have included a screenshot of your recommendation in the original post.

Did you read the entire answer? I have my doubts.

Yes, of course I read the whole thing. I'm struggling to understand your answer because the very first sentence of the answer seems to contradict the very last sentence. My question specifically mentions that I want links from third party apps to open Explorer links in new Tabs. So the answer is no I guess, not yes as stated in the first sentence.

No. There are 0 contradictions. It's as if I said "Yes, the weather can be sunny in California". Which is true most of the time but has exceptions. I listed the exceptions quite specifically, you also mentioned one of the exceptions I listed. Nothing you can do about the exceptions, except switching to a different app, but you can use the functionality problemlessly most of the time.

Yes, you are right, sorry for the confusion. Your answer makes perfect sense. Still hoping there is a solution for me.

No problem, good luck, but this app is pretty much dead and there's nothing else.
